# Z170 or H170 motherboard with M.2

Tags: motherboard

I need a Z170 or H170 motherboard that allows an M.2-2280 PCIe 3.0 x4 SSD and still has one PCIe 3.0 x16 open.

PCPartPicker part list: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/xMkhqk
Price breakdown by merchant: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/xMkhqk/by_merchant/

CPU: Intel Core i5-6600 3.3GHz Quad-Core Processor  ($200.00)
Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) DDR4-2133 Memory  ($104.99 @ Newegg)
Storage: Samsung SM951 128GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive  ($105.99 @ Amazon)
Case: Fractal Design Define S ATX Mid Tower Case  ($69.99 @ SuperBiiz)
Monitor: Dell P2415Q 23.8" 60Hz Monitor  ($280.00)
Total: $760.97
Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available
Generated by PCPartPicker 2016-07-06 06:12 EDT-0400

Comment: Do you have a budget for this motherboard?